# JavaScript delay before looping

Tags: javascript

I am a complete noob at coding and have a quick question. Below is a snipet of code and what I need to do is, if the process repeats (i.e., ctr < end) then I need it to wait for 2 minutes before doing so.  I don't want to lock down the computer, this will be running a background task.  I have researched and while I might have found a solution in setTimeout(), I can't implement it properly with my limited knowledge. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
 if (ctr < end) {
    return function() {
     otherFunction(ctr + 1);
        };
```

Comment: You really can't figure it out, even after reading [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)?

Answer (score 0):

Basic Example demonstrating [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

```js
var ctr = 0;
var end = 5;
mainLoop();

// some function
function mainLoop() {
  // checks current ctr to end then increments ctr by 1
  if (ctr++ < end) {
    // log the value of ctr
    console.log(ctr);
    // This is set to happen every 2 seconds
    // 2 minutes is 2 * 60 * 1000 = 120000 milliseconds
    // calls the mainLoop function after 2000 milliseconds
    setTimeout(mainLoop, 2000);
  } else {
    // prints it is over after the ctr is equal or greater than end
    console.log('it is over');
  }
}
```